# How can I display/upload a picture from mobile?

Tags: support, user-interface, images

Yes I am a mobile user. Recently I had an question in which I needed to upload an image but didn't found the option! Can I do this from my mobile or the only way is to paste the imgur link?

Comment: What mobile platform are you using?  I have no problem uploading images in the standard way on my phone.

Comment: Currently I'm not on android or iOS, I am using Asha OS from Nokia, simply I browse M.SE through Opera Mini v4.5